# copy variable name with some order in python

Tags: python-3.x, variables

like to copy some variable with some calculation.
There is a list and I want to make multiple lists by copy the list.

```
fruit=['apple','orange']
```

below lists I want to create from original list

```
fruit1=['apple1','orange1']  
fruit2=['apple2','orange2']                               
fruit3=['apple3','orange3']
```

please help

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read up on [ask].

Comment: Are you asking how to create an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import inspect

fruit = ['apple', 'orange']


def get(v):
    for i in reversed(inspect.stack()):
        n = [v_name for v_name, v_val in i.frame.f_locals.items() if v_val is v]
        if len(n):
            return n[0]


for i in range(1, 4):
    name_string_order = get(fruit) + str(i)
    exec("%s = [fruit[0] + str(i), fruit[1] + str(i)]" % name_string_order)


print(fruit1)
print(fruit2)
print(fruit3)
```

And out put

```
['apple1', 'orange1']
['apple2', 'orange2']
['apple3', 'orange3']
```